# Filter many subdomains Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a website `www.xxx.com` with an universal Google Analytics code that's run on all the subdomains`wwww.yyy.xxx.com` `wwww.zzz.xxx.com` for example. There are over 300 subdomains.

In my Google Analytics, I would like to filter those, so I still can see the raw data for all sites, but also for each subdomain. I just realized, that I can't filter existing data - is that true?

I have tried to set up some filters according to [this guide](http://www.netcel.com/Resources/Insights/White-papers/6-must-have-google-analytics-filters/) and it works fine. The problem is, that I have over 300 pages, can I automate this somehow? And is it true, that I can't get some reports somehow over existing data with new filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have up to 50 views (profiles) in one GA account, so to ask if you can automate 300 is a moot point.

You could use segments which have the advantage of being able to work on historical data (which view filter can indeed not do). However I don't think the interface supports 300 Segments.

If you use the API you can programmatically create segments on the fly when you pull data, but of course then you don't have the nice interface and would have to create you own reports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also figured out, that I can add a second dimension to many of the reports, which I set to the hostname, and then make an advanced search... This also helps me a bit!

Comment: Or simply use customVar/custom dimension to store the subdomain itself, which should make filtering/segmenting a bit easier.

Comment: @PetrHavlík, that's already covered by the "hostname" dimension which also records the subdomains.